# Transformation to center 3D object in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I want to center the 3D object on the screen and be able to rotate/scale it. While doing the rotation/scaling the object center is still at the same place. (similar to MeshLab presentation).

This is my vertex shader:

```
gl_Position = mvp * vec4(VertexPosition,1.0);
```

And here is my modelview matrix in client code:

```
mat4 mvp = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1), vec3(-centerx, -centery, -centerz));
mvp = glm::scale(view, vec3(0.5/zoom, 0.5/zoom, 0.5/zoom));
```

Centerx, centery etc is the center of the object. Zoom is max size of object (so that it appears between -1 and 1). How do I get to the correct transformation? Is there any other things I needed?

[image]

This is a box, where I colored it by vertex position.

Comment: You have to translate its center to the origin before applying rotation, then translate back. You've sort of done this, but your operations are out-of-order. `scale * -trans_center * rotation * trans_center` should work. Right now `mvp` seems to just be a scale matrix, you threw out the translation 1 line above it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with glm, but my guess would be that you have to **update the matrix in the shader**. You can do this with a function like `glUniformMatrix*(mvp, ...)`.

When you manipulate the matrix or other variables that you want to use in a shader, you have to send this updates to your shader, otherwise it won't have any effect.